# I put filelist[i] to ${}, It become to undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, discord.js, fs

I get filelist on './src/commands', and this files will require to map array called 'cmds'.
and I want if folder in './src/commands/', also require file in the folder to map array's 2-D array.

I do Debugging Many Arrays, and Variable, but I don't catch why that is changing.

```
fs.readdir('./src/commands', function(err, fl) {
    if (err) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < fl.length; i++) {
        if (!fl[i].endsWith('.js')) {
            fs.readdir(`./src/commands/${fl[i]}`, function(err, flin) {
                if (err) return;
                cmds[fl[i]] = {};
                for (var j = 0; j < flin.length; j++) {
                    cmds[fl[i]][flin[j].split(".js")[0]] = require(`./commands/${fl[i]}/${flin[j]}`);
                    console.log(`${fl[i]}/${flin[j]} loaded!`);
                }
            });
            continue;
        }
        cmds[fl[i].split(".js")[0]] = require(`./commands/${fl[i]}`);
        console.log(`${fl[i]} loaded!`);
    }
});
```

Error Message:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './commands/undefined/test.js'
Require stack:
- E:\git-project\VitaBot\src\main.js
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)[39m
[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)[39m
[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)[39m
    at E:\git-project\VitaBot\src\main.js:15:60
[90m    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:153:23)[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: [ [32m'E:\\git-project\\VitaBot\\src\\main.js'[39m ]
```

I think it will naturally require, but that's not.

Comment: For starters, change `var i` to `let i` so your `i` variable is unique for each iteration of the `for` loop and will work with asynchronous operations that run later.  I don't know what the rest of this code is doing or what you're asking, but this is definitely  a problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks you very much.  I solved the problem that was causing me pain. I'll use let in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change `var i` to `let i` so your i variable is unique for each iteration of the for loop and will work with asynchronous operations that run later.

In your code, the `for` loop runs to its completion.  In each iteration of the loop, it starts an `fs.readdir()` operation, but since that is non-blocking and asynchronous, it doesn't finish right away.  Instead, the next iteration of the loop runs and starts another one.  This completes until the `for` loop is completely done.  Then, sometime later, your first `fs.readdir()` operation completes and calls its callback and that callback runs.  But, at this point your one index variable `i` is pointing beyond the end of the `for` loop which means that `fl[i]` will point beyond the end of the `fl` array and you get only an `undefined` value.  This will then happen for all the `fs.readdir()` callbacks as they each get called.

`let i`, on the otherhand, creates a new variable `i` for each separate iteration of the loop so when your  `fs.readdir()` callback runs it is still seeing the desired value of `i` for its iteration of the `for` loop.